# Box plot con Python

Tags: python, plotly

Estoy realizando unas representaciones mediante box plots, los datos que yo tengo son los siguientes:

```
id     Times
1      480
2      391
3      269
4      205
5      157
6      99
7      70
8      35
9      21
```

Entonces lo que hago para representar el diagrama de caja y bigote es crear un alista en la que habría 480 unos, 391 doses, etc

Lista = [1,1,1,1,.....,2,2,2,2,..........]

Habría alguna forma de indicarle esto sin tener que crear la lista?

El código con el que pinto esto es:

```
traces.append(go.Box(y=lista_frecuencias, name="Box plot", marker ={"size":4}))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por desgracia no. La función `Box()` de Plotly no soporta otro tipo de entrada. Tienes que pasarle las muestras concretas, y él se ocupa de calcular las estadísticas.

Es más, ni siquiera admite que se le pase un *iterable*, es necesario pasarle una lista (o Pandas Series, o array Numpy). Es una pena, porque si admitiera un iterable como parámetro, nos podríamos ahorrar el espacio en memoria de esa lista, pues el iterable es *lazy* y va generando cada elemento a medida que se le pide, en lugar de tener que generarlos todos de antemano para meterlos en la lista.

Haciendo uso de las funciones en `itertools` podría crearse el iterable necesario con una sola línea de código. Veamos como.

De entrada necesitamos un diccionario en el que las claves sean los números, y los valores sean el número de veces que se repite cada uno. Si esa información la tienes en un dataframe como el que pones al inicio de la pregunta, y suponiendo que "id" sea el índice del dataframe, puedes extraerlo en forma de diccionario así:

```
freq = df.to_dict()["Times"]
```

Una vez lo tenemos así, el iterable se construiría con la siguiente línea:

```
from itertools import chain, repeat
lista_frecuencias = chain.from_iterable(repeat(elem, n) for elem, n in freq.items())
```

Por desgracia, si intentamos pasar ese iterable a `Box()`, da error:

```
traces.append(go.Box(
   y=lista_frecuencias, 
   name="Box plot", 
   marker ={"size":4}))
```

```
ValueError: 
    Invalid value of type 'itertools.chain' received for the 'y' property of box
        Received value: <itertools.chain object at 0x7f706ea06e80>

    The 'y' property is an array that may be specified as a tuple,
    list, numpy array, or pandas Series
```

Así que no nos queda más remedio que convertirlo en lista:

```
traces.append(go.Box(
   y=list(lista_frecuencias), 
   name="Box plot", 
   marker ={"size":4}))
```

Con lo que en el fondo terminamos con una solución equivalente a la tuya. Espero que al menos los "truquillos" de `itertools` te puedan servir para hacer el código más compacto, y ahorrarte unos cuantos bucles.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, te viene a la cabez alguna otra librería en vez de plotly con la que sí se pueda hacer algo así? Usaré lo de los iteradores y me ahorraré algunos bucles. Saludos